# Continued Trouble Uploading to Android Marketplace - "The server could not process your apk. Try again." Is there any support for this issue?

Tags: process, upload, apk

I've attempted to upload a new apk file to the Android marketplace and I continue to get the following error.
 “The server could not process your apk. Try again."

This has been an ongoing issue. I've researched this issue and it seems it is a common issue and should be easily solved. But the message "Android Marketplace Error: “The server could not process your apk. Try again." is cryptic and leaves me with no where to go.

In all other markets, Apple, Barnes & Noble, and Amazon, I can talk directly with the support staff and get a satisfactory answer. The Android marketplace seems like the wild west and everyone is on their own.

I've posted this message in Google Groups and I have not got an answer. It seems that a lot of people are having a similar problem have not solved the issue. Here are some sample responses:

"Best of luck. You're going to need it."
"Same problem here - this is going on for over a year and is still not solved"
Has anyone every had this issue and solved it?

Who can I contact to solve this issue?

I don't have anymore ideas on how to solve this.